# Make a flex class from Bootstrap 4 take full height of the table cell parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I am using Bootstrap 4 CSS and JS (from the official CDN), along with Font Awesome 5 (also official CDN).

I was originally using the `text-center` class from Bootstrap, since FA5 icons are just text. Then I tried using `text-justify` to make the icons dispersed better on larger-width displays, but this didn't work at all.

Here is the table cell part of the markup. I didn't want to paste the whole thing here because the templating (Jinja2) is fairly long.

```
<td>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-up"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-star"></i>
  </div>
</td>
```

Table cell displays as expected except it is not full height and the icons look off-center.

[image: table cell screenshot]

Does anyone have a fairly simple way to make the `d-flex` element use the full height of the parent cell? Or just a better way in general to make up-vote, down-vote, and favorite icons fit well within a table cell? I also need to figure out a way to make the current scores / favorites number align well with all of the other cells in the table. Any existing solutions or advice you have would be very helpful as well.

**Edit:** As an afterthought, I should add that these icons will eventually be inside of buttons if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post JSfiddle to get better idea about the problem ?

Comment: @pradeepkumar That's a lot of effort to port my template to a JSFiddle for something so trivial. What information is missing? Maybe I could add it to the post instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use align-items-center bootstrap class to align your elements center of the cell. If you used any custom line-height, Kindly remove it.

```
<td>
      <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-up"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-star"></i>
      </div>
    </td>
```

Note: The question was not clear to me. I gave the solution to align your fa icons vertically center to the cells. Hope u asking the same...

Comment: This dooesn't change the appearance of anything.

Answer (score 0):

You say the icons will eventually be inside of buttons. Why not use a button group? Or use bootstraps col classes to align things. Set the height of the button 100% to take up the full height of the cell.
Both ideas shown below.

I hope this helps

```css
td{
  height: 100px;
}
.btn, .btn-group{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
             <span class="col-sm-4">
           <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-up"></i>
             </span>
             <span class="col-sm-4">
                  <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-down"></i>
             </span>
             <span class="col-sm-4">
                  <i class="fas fa-fw fa-star"></i>
             </span>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-up"></i>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chevron-down"></i>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-star"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using `.container-fluid` with `.d-flex`? Use another parent tag for container-fluid class.

Comment: I mean to say is that mostly the .container-fluid is used for wrapping the as a parent div so there is no use of using it inside with .d-flex if you remove the .container-fluid it may help